# Showing/Hiding specific divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twig

I'm using jQuery in a twig template to show or hide certain div. To explain the context I have a comment area and I just want to display the form for commenting when the user click on a certain link. However, these divs are generated through a "for" loop (because each comment has a link to answer this particular comment). Then I have to set specific ids for each answer div and his respective link. This doesn't look very hard to do, but I'm stuck and I really don't understand why... I'm not sure I'm clear so here is my code :

Twig:

```
{% for commentaire in article.commentaires %}
<div>
    // display comment

    {% for reponse in commentaire.reponses %}
        // display answer
    {% endfor %}

        <a id="lien-reponse[{{ commentaire.id }}]" class="lien-reponse" href="#">Répondre au commentaire</a>
        <div id="div-lien-reponse[{{ commentaire.id }}]" style="display:none">
            // form to answer the comment
        </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

In this code I want to display the div #div-lien-reponse[xx] when the user clicks the link #lien-reponse[xx]. Here is the query code :

Jquery:

```
$('.lien-reponse').click(function(event) {
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
 $('#'+id).hide();
 $('#div-'+id).show("slow");
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

But when I click on the link, it doesn't do anything on the page (but no # appears on the url, so I guess the call to the jquery function is good). I'm not very good at jQuery so perhaps I'm missing something really obvious, or a simpler way to do that.

Thanks in advance, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: please check using firebug...and see what it says..

Comment: Try an `alert()` statement to see what `id` and `'#'+id` are carrying.

Comment: Are you in $(document).ready statement ?
Is this script executed after jQuery is loaded ?

Comment: Seems same ids for multiple element instances.

Comment: No Jai, I guess thoses comments have differents ids... And #lien-reponse1 is not equal to #div-lien-reponse1.

Comment: @ASGM: I've already checked with alerts and the var id is ok. Flo: yes and yes. Jai: the ids are different, the {{ commentaire.id }} displays a unique id for each comment.

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby Both of the elems links with id and div and the wrapper of it without an id that is also in a loop, so basically same ids are looping in the wrapper `div` and wrapper `div` is also in a loop.

Comment: Could you check your JavaScript console and show if there is any error ?
Try console.log($(this)); that should give you a link element, and console.log($('#div-' + id)); that should give you the div you want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all ... **since your id has `[]` character you need to escape that to use it in a selector**...so  i think its  better if you use `next()`.. if the div is next to the link always

```
$(function(){  //document.ready function 
  $('.lien-reponse').click(function(event) {
     $(this).next().show('slow');  // OR $(this).next('div').show('slow');
     event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: I gave the answer to ZNS as I believe he answered before but thanks for your contribution. It works well now !

Comment: hehe... it was me who answered before.. notice the time...and i was 2 mins ahead of him..anyways glad it helped.. happy coding.. :) :)

Comment: That's true, and yours is also more explanatory so I changed the answer :D. Thanks both of you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep track of all those id's. Use the DOM instead.

```
$('.lien-reponse').click(function(event) {
    $(this).next("div").toggle();
}
```

Comment: You are right, this is way simpler. I didn't know this trick. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Symfony2 and Twig, just ensure that your script is called after jQuery !

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
    <!--<script src='{{ asset('bundles/yourbundle/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js') }}'></script>-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(document).on('click', '.lien-reponse', function(event) { // equivalent to $('.lien-reponse').click()
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).next().show('slow');
                // You can also chain your jQuery dom manipulation:
                // $(this).hide().next().show('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Jquery is called in my layout and I'm using `{% block js %}
 {{ parent() }}
 <script src="{{ asset('js/commentaires.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}` to load my js file so I guess it's ok, right ?

Comment: Yeah, looks fine, check with the JS console on Chrome so !